# How to find the python list item that start with

Tags: python

I have the list that contains some items like:

```
"GFS01_06-13-2017 05-10-18-38.csv"
"Metadata_GFS01_06-13-2017 05-10-18-38.csv"
```

How to find the list item that start with `"GFS01_"`

In SQL I use query: `select item from list where item like 'GFS01_%'`

Comment: `[x for x in list if x.startswith('GFS01_')]` returns a list of items that startswith what you want

Comment: Thanks @Ludisposed, its working

Comment: and if you **just** want to get the next item with that property you can do `next(x for x in list if x.startswith('GFS01_'))`

Comment: Result will give ['GFS01_06-13-2017 05-10-18-38.csv'], how to remove [' & '], please help

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You have several options, but most obvious are:

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a condition:

```python
result = [i for i in some_list if i.startswith('GFS01_')]
```

Using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) (which returns [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator))

```python
result = filter(lambda x: x.startswith('GFS01_'), some_list)
```

Comment: Result will give ['GFS01_06-13-2017 05-10-18-38.csv'], how to remove/replace [' & ']

Comment: @linus What do you mean by  _remove/replace [' & ']_ ?

Comment: I want to replace " [' " and " '] " with blank from results

Comment: @linus  I don't fully understand your problem, but there should not be any other items in results apart from those started with 'GFS01_'.

Comment: (str(sourceFileName).replace("['","")).replace("']","") this is working...if you have better version please update...

Comment: It retuns in the form of a list, if you want output in form of string do `for x in result: print x` I suggest looking up some of the basics of lists in the pythondocs

Comment: @Learnings to do that you should use:
`result = [i.strip("[]") for i in some_list if i.startswith('GFS01_')]`

Answer (score 4):

You should try something like this :

```
[item for item in my_list if item.startswith('GFS01_')]
```

where "my_list" is your list of items.

Comment: Result will give ['GFS01_06-13-2017 05-10-18-38.csv'], how to remove/replace [' & ']

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the string output like this "GFS01_06-13-2017 05-10-18-38.csv","GFS01_xxx-xx-xx.csv", you could try this:

```
', '.join([item for item in myList if item.startswith('GFS01_')])
```

Or with quotes

```
', '.join(['"%s"' % item for item in myList if item.startswith('GFS01_')])
```

Filtering of list will gives you list again and that needs to be handled as per you requirement then.