# Fast way to find if list of words contains at least one word that starts with certain letters (not "find ALL words"!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, any

I have set (not list) of strings (words). It is a big one. (It's ripped out of images with **openCV** and **tesseract** so there's no reliable way to predict its contents.)

At some point of working with this list I need to find out if it contains at least one word that begins with part I'm currently processing.
So it's like (NOT an actual code):

```
if exists(word.startswith(word_part) in word_set) then continue else break
```

There is a very good answer on how to find all strings in list that start with something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517191/how-to-find-the-python-list-item-that-start-with):

```
result = [s for s in string_list if s.startswith(lookup)]
```

or

```
result = filter(lambda s: s.startswith(lookup), string_list)
```

But they return `list` or `iterator` of all strings found.
I only need to find if any such string exists within set, not get them all.
Performance-wise it seems kinda stupid to get list, then get its `len` and see if it's more than zero and then just drop that list.

It there a better / faster / cleaner way?

Comment: you could just `re.search("[\b]lookup_term",original_block_of_text))` ... but it still is O(N) ... you could make a set of the `word[:len(lookup_term)]` instead of the whole word ... but still takes O(N) to build that set (but then very fast lookup)...

Comment: If you want short-circuit, why not `if any(word.startswith(word_part) for word in wordset)`?

Comment: If you want to make this check more performant, you should store your strings in a prefix trie (see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015320/how-to-create-a-trie-in-python or use a real library), otherwise just use `any` as others have already mentioned.

Comment: `sort` + `bisect` + `startswith`.

Comment: Joran Beasely, no, that won't do, I need to do that multiple times. with different-*length* starting letter sets. so building a different list for looking up is too performance-heavy.

Chris, yes, that's exactly what I need, I'm just beginning coding in python so I didn't know about "any" yet, thank you!

Boris, that's too data-science for a former web developer like me. Not my level yet, but thanks for pointing. I'll look in that direction later, when I'll have more experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudocode is very close to real code!

```
if any(word.startswith(word_part) for word in word_set):
    continue
else:
    break
```

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) returns as soon as it finds one true element, so it's efficient.

Comment: exactly what I need, thank you! I'm just starting learning python (about 10 days ago wrote my very first script that's more than "print('this is a drill')"-lookalikes) so some things I just didn't encounter yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`yield`](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/):

```
def find_word(word_set, letter):
    for word in word_set:
        if word.startswith(letter):
            yield word
    yield None
if next(find_word(word_set, letter)): print('word exists')
```

Yield gives out words lazily. So if you call it once, it will give out only one word.

Comment: i dont think you need the cast to iter ... generators automatically are iterators `next(find_word(word_set,letter))`

Comment: is this faster / lighter than above example? it surely is more code :) but, definitely _way_ more human-readable!

Comment: Timed it, and this one is pretty faster as compared to the other one. But now I am not exactly sure why. It is almost like the implementation of any, which is used in the other answer. May be @JoranBeasley can elaborate?

Comment: based on dis.dis it has to maybe build an extra function ... but honestly im a bit surprised that its faster to do this than any ... not blown away but surprised ... but i think its pretty close to the same between both methods ...

Comment: I would not be blown away as well, until I found [this massive difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386919/why-is-any-slower-than-yield-for-checking-if-any-element-exists-matching-conditi)