# Why is any() slower than yield for checking if any element exists matching condition

Tags: python, performance, generator, yield, any

I was answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385512/fast-way-to-find-if-list-of-words-contains-at-least-one-word-that-starts-with-ce/59385573#59385573), and used `yield` for the solution, and another answer used `any`.
Prompted by OP, I timed the two, and found `yield` significantly outperforms `any`.
I tested for more general case:

> Find if any number exists that is greater than 460 in natural numbers upto 1000.

Here's the performance:

```
setup = """
z = list(range(1000))
def check(lst):
    for l in lst:
        if l>460:
            yield True
    yield False"""
timeit.timeit('next(check(z))',setup=setup)
# 9.688747814000635
timeit.timeit('any(_z>460 for _z in z)',setup='z = list(range(1000))')
# 21.593566988999555
```

My question is, `any` uses short-circuit evaluation, and breaks as soon as a match is found, and `yield` halts when it finds the first match, then ***why is this massive difference between `yield` and `any`?***

**NOTE**: Python version: 3.7.3, OS: Windows 10 64-bit
(found similar results on CentOS, python 3.6)