# Extracting item from list

Tags: python, list, extract

On Python I have a list like:

```
["Years : 1970 - aaaaa", "Month : May - aaaaaaaaa", "Day : 20 - aaaaaaa", "Years : 1971 - aaaaa"]
```

I just need to extract all items starting by "Years" in another list to have a list like:

```
["Years : 1970 - aaaaaaa", Years :  1971 - aaaaaaaa"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Have you checked the website for an answer prior to posting this? I thought that this answer [how to find the python list item that starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517191/how-to-find-the-python-list-item-that-start-with) , might have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with list comprehension:

```
[i for i in lst if i.startswith('Years')]
```

Basically, it says *For all i elements, return i if it starts with 'Years'*